# Categorize results based on Model in haystack?

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-haystack, whoosh

When we search using the **SearchQuerySet API** provided by **django-haystack** the result is a list containing objects of model instances across all of the indexes.

Now for post computation I want to categorize search result based on the model from which they were fetched.

Normally I would do something like this

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
hello_results = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='hello')
```

I can iterate over the list of models and the use **.models()** to query specifically using a single index.
But I think this approach will be much slower as multiple searches will have to be executed.

Is there a better approach to accomplish the same.

EDIT:

By this I mean:

Let there be two models A and B ,

Now by some means I want to know that which of the results were fetched from model A and which ones from Model B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each result has an attribute `model_name`. So you can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in your view, or check `result.model_name` when looping through the result in your search results template.